# PowerShell Group Object Multiple Properties when Equal?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, hashtable

I have an object with properties such as username and destination IP. I'm attempting to count whenever the username and IP are the same and produce that number, so I can work with those results whenever a threshold is met. However, I'm not sure how to go about this. I thought group-object might work, but since it's not just a single property I'm stumped.

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Data example:**

```
username, destination IP
abuckey, 10.10.10.10
dfumley, 11.11.11.11
```

**Code Example:**
This will group by the username:

```
$ReportObject | Group-Object -Property "Username"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify both properties:

```
$ReportObject | Group-Object -Property username,'destination IP'
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be that easy. Thank you so much!